# How to calculate the dfference between two variables in Django?

Tags: jquery, django

I'm creating an aircraft comparison site.

Say for example we have this table:

```
          Aircraft
     | A350  | 777-330 |
     |-----------------|
Range| 8,943 |  7,354  |
     -------------------
```

What I essential want to do is calculate the difference, but the user may select B777 first which has a lower range than the A350, resulting in a negative number (-1589).

I want to write a function where the computer realises that the bigger number should come first and calculate the difference, but where will this piece of code go - in the view or jquery?

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer, it makes no sense to do this in javascript if you intend to use it on the backend, and if its on the backend then is this inside a queryset? What have you tried?

Comment: @Sayse It makes absolute sense.

Comment: I disagree, why should the client have to do a computation for something that it doesn't need to worry about? Either way, it appears that Rory McCrossan's answer solved your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want a positive result from the calculation you don't need to re-order the arguments, you can just use `Math.abs()`, like this:

```js
var result = 7354 - 8943;
console.log('Result:', result);
console.log('Absolute value:', Math.abs(result));
```